# How to Make an Element Disappear from the Screen Completely Without It Glitching?

Tags: javascript, html

So, I attempted three different ways to make an element disappear completely from the screen (displayed in the code below). Whenever I refresh the page, for each solution I tried, it has a glitch of some sort. By glitch, I mean, when I refresh the site, it shows the original text and quickly takes the text off. I'm wondering if there is a way of preventing this from happening by doing it in an alternative way.

EDIT: I am trying to make my own JS framework so inline is not really the route I want to go.

```js
// WAY 1
let elementWay1 = document.getElementById('demo1');
elementWay1.remove();

// WAY 2
let elementWay2 = document.getElementById('demo2');
elementWay2.style.display = 'none';

// WAY 3
let elementWay3 = document.getElementById('demo3');
elementWay3.style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p id="demo1">HelloSo, I attempted three different ways to make an element disappear completely from the screen (displayed in the code below). Whenever I refresh the page, for each solution I tried, it has a glitch of some sort. By glitch, I mean, when I refresh the site, it shows the original text and quickly takes the text off. I'm wondering if there is a way of preventing this from happening by doing it in an alternative way.So, I attempted three different ways to make an element disappear completely from the screen (displayed in the code below). Whenever I refresh the page, for each solution I tried, it has a glitch of some sort. By glitch, I mean, when I refresh the site, it shows the original text and quickly takes the text off. I'm wondering if there is a way of preventing this from happening by doing it in an alternative way.</p>
    <p id="demo2">HelloSo, I attempted three different ways to make an element disappear completely from the screen (displayed in the code below). Whenever I refresh the page, for each solution I tried, it has a glitch of some sort. By glitch, I mean, when I refresh the site, it shows the original text and quickly takes the text off. I'm wondering if there is a way of preventing this from happening by doing it in an alternative way.So, I attempted three different ways to make an element disappear completely from the screen (displayed in the code below). Whenever I refresh the page, for each solution I tried, it has a glitch of some sort. By glitch, I mean, when I refresh the site, it shows the original text and quickly takes the text off. I'm wondering if there is a way of preventing this from happening by doing it in an alternative way.</p>
    <p id="demo3">HelloSo, I attempted three different ways to make an element disappear completely from the screen (displayed in the code below). Whenever I refresh the page, for each solution I tried, it has a glitch of some sort. By glitch, I mean, when I refresh the site, it shows the original text and quickly takes the text off. I'm wondering if there is a way of preventing this from happening by doing it in an alternative way.So, I attempted three different ways to make an element disappear completely from the screen (displayed in the code below). Whenever I refresh the page, for each solution I tried, it has a glitch of some sort. By glitch, I mean, when I refresh the site, it shows the original text and quickly takes the text off. I'm wondering if there is a way of preventing this from happening by doing it in an alternative way.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

*I know that the code result in an error, because I included all three ways in the code.*

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the page is large enough that there is at least a slight delay in between when the element gets rendered and when the script runs. You could mitigate this by reducing the page size and/or putting the script inline instead of linking to externally via `script src`. To make sure it runs as soon as possible, I'd put the script immediately after the element you want to remove, eg:

```
<p id="demo">Hello</p>
<script>
document.getElementById('demo').remove();
</script>
```

or at least, have the `<script>` be not too far separated from the `#demo` element. Don't wait for the whole document to load (don't wait for `DOMContentLoaded`) before running the script.

Comment: I'm trying to make my own little framework, so inline wouldn't really work in this case. I guess I should have stated that in the question. @CertainPerformance

Comment: Can you elaborate on why figuring out a way for the script to run more quickly wouldn't work? Whether you're trying to build a framework or not shouldn't affect the efficacy of the solution

Comment: Well, I mean, I feel that it is important for the code to run more efficiently, in general, for user's sake. However, with all due respect, I don't quite know how to explain something that I'm asking about, that's the reason I'm asking. I just need to know if there is a different and more efficient way to doing this to where it does not glitch. I don't know to minimize the screen size, I can't do that on other people's screens to where it will work in theirs as well. :)

Comment: i updated your snippet.  I don't think you can avoid the lag.  The page has to load first before you can delete, remove or hide an element.  if the element contains a lot your stuck

Comment: @user15155940 I don't understand what efficiency has to do with this - I don't see anything in the question or the answer that would have any notable impact on efficiency. (except for the fact that you appear to have a whole lot of HTML content which is causing the delay)

Comment: @DCR If the issue was that the page wasn't loaded when the script ran, the issue wouldn't be the flashing element, but the element wouldn't disappear at all.

Comment: Unable to reproduce problem with code provided

Comment: @DCR The problem will appear if there is some delay between when the element gets rendered and when the script runs. For example, add a large image and run the code after a `load` listener. Or have a large page that takes some time to download, with the `<script>` at the end. Or make the script have a `src`, and server-side, add a delay before serving the script. All of these will result in the problem OP's describing.